# Implementing a index for text file content

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a text file with a huge number of words( ~50MB ). For building an index for this file content , which data structure is best suited ?

Or using what data structure , I can achieve best results while searching ?

Thanks in advance

Jijoy

Comment: It usually helps if you provide more details about the file structure and what are you trying to search for...

Comment: Why can't you just put the data in a database and let that organise the data for the fastest search results (i.e. indices on the criteria you will search the data by)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is a dictionary of words a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is well-suited.

Answer (score 2):

you can cut-off the overhead of using data structures and writing an algorithm using some library like [lucene][1]

[1]: http://lucene.apache.org/. I am not much sure for your case whether it will be right but when in java one have to create indices for files and have to perform some search operations using these indices the usage of lucene is considered fair.

Answer (score 0):

A B+ Tree would be quite efficient if you were thinking of it like a table, however if it is simply a large list of words you could give Fibonacci trees a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for full text indexing, then a suffix array is a great choice:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array

If you just want an in-memory inverted index, then a hash table might be best.